Do magnetic force depend on frame of reference?
Consider two point charges
If both charge are moving with velocity v in same direction with respect to a inertial frame of reference. Will the magnetic force would be zero between them?
If one charge is at rest and another is moving. Will the the moving experience a force due to that stationary charge?
And how this all is connected to special relativity?

Does this answer your question? Moving charge in different frames of reference

Does this answer your question? Does protons moving parallel to each other exert magnetic force?
